# DatePickerDialog not working as expected

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, datepickerdialog

I have an `EditView` in which I am trying to bind `DatePickerDialog`. Its working well with the **api 19**. but when tested on **api version 25** Marshmallow the calendar becomes white and when selected some date the `EditView` is not populated as well i.e I am unable to set date in **Marshmallow**.

**Code:**

```
warrantyExpEt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), date, myCalendar
                        .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
            }
        });


    final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                                  int dayOfMonth) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                updateLabel();
            }

        };
        private void updateLabel() {

            String myFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);

            warrantyExpEt.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
        }
```

Comment: post your style folder.

Answer (score 1):

this might be the Theme you are using in your project. So use below theme in your style file

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
   <item name="colorPrimary">@color/green_sheet</item>
   <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>     
</style>
```

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: I am extending my AppTheme from AppTheme.Base <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

Comment: just try with above theme example

Answer (score 1):

Remove this from your style:

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to this it can show dialog as you want

```
   new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, R.style.datepicker, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);

        }
    }, year, month, day).show();
```

**dialog style as you wish**

```
  <style name="datepicker" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">

    <item name="colorAccent">@color/red</item>
</style>
```